# why does my heat pump wiring diagram show 7 wires going to the thermostat but the thermostat only says it needs 5?

Tags: wiring, hvac, heating, thermostat, heat-pump

[Here](http://flic.kr/p/kNFU6H) is a link to the wiring diagram for my heat pump.  The thermostat that I am planning on buying has the following terminals C, G, Y, O/B, RC, R, Aux, E, and L.  The [instructions](http://flic.kr/p/kNHaMa) say to jump the RC and R together after you connect the R wire.  On the wiring diagram I can see where the the R, Y, G, and O wires match up on the Heat pump(HP) and the thermostat(TS).  It looks like to me the W2 on the HP connects to the W on the TS and the C from the HP connects with the B on the TS.  It also looks like the W1 on the HP does not connect to the TS but to another place in the HP.  I thought there would be wires going from  W1 and W2 on the HP to the same terminals on the TS(if I understand correctly that W1 and W2 are 2 different heat settings)?  On the wiring diagram on the HP it looks like it wants 7 wires connected from the HP to the TS, however on the Thermostat instructions it only shows 5 wires being connected...any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The below are all you have to worry about, Yellow need not be wired to Y at the air handler
as it is a dummy trminal for convenience, many simply run Y from the stat to the AC unit outside bypassing the Y terminal on the air handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your thermostat is not wired for 2-stage.